# How Do I Publish A Renamed bootJar?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am in a gradle 4.10 Spring Boot project called `rest` and in my `build.gradle` I have renamed the boot jar that is created by adding

```
bootJar.baseName = 'myprefix-rest'
```

When I run `./gradlew bootJar` it creates a file called `myprefix-rest-0.1.jar` as expected.

However, when I add the `maven-publish` publish plugin and try to publish, it publishes the file called `rest-0.1.jar`

```
publishing {
  publications {
    bootJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifact bootJar
    }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = "$buildDir"
    }
  }
}
```

Why is it not picking up the `baseName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it not picking up the baseName?

From the [MavenPublication docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html),

> The default Maven POM identifying attributes are mapped as follows:
>
> ```
> groupId - project.group
> artifactId - project.name
> version - project.version
> ```

so the actual file name of the boot jar file is not being used. You can overrride the artifactId,

```
publishing {
  publications {
    bootJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifact bootJar
      artifactId bootJar.baseName
    }
  }
  ..
}
```